# Combining 2 columns in R prioriziting one of them

Tags: r, merge, multiple-columns

I know nothing of R, and I have a data.frame with 2 columns, both of them are about the sex of the animals, but one of them have some corrections and the other doesn't.

My desired data.frame would be like this:

```
    id  sex  father mother birth.date  farm
    0    1    john   ray   05/06/94     1
    1    1    doug   ana   18/02/93     NA
    2    2    bryan  kim   21/03/00     3
```

But i got to this data.frame by using merge on 2 others data.frames

```
  id sex.x father mother birth.date sex.y farm
    0    2    john   ray    05/06/94    1     1
    1    1    doug   ana    18/02/93    NA    NA
    2    2    bryan  kim    21/03/00    2     3
```

data.frame 1 or Animals (Has the wrong sex for some animals)

```
 id sex father mother birth.date
  0  2   john   ray    05/06/94
  1  1   doug   ana    18/02/93
  2  2   bryan  kim    21/03/00
```

data.frame 2 or Farm (Has the correct sex):

```
 id farm sex
  0  1    1
  2  3    2
```

The code i used was: `Animals_Farm <- merge(Animals , Farm, by="id", all.x=TRUE)`

I need to combine the 2 sex columns into one, prioritizing sex.y. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to R. Check this highly tagged Q. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Then try to provide details of input data, what is your desired output.

Comment: This would be a good task for `coalesce` from package dplyr.

Comment: `sex <- ifelse(!is.na(sex.y), sex.y, sex.x)`

Comment: How i use this sex <- ? I tried like this ifelse(!is.na(Animais_Farm$sex.y), Animais_Farm$sex.y, Animais_Farm$sex.x)

Comment: So you need this `merge(df, df1[,-3], by="id", all.x=TRUE)`?

Comment: @Sotos With that line, farm didnt appeared, but sex.x and sex.y yes

Comment: oh ok. I get it... I think you simply need (given that your merged data frame is called `df2`), then `df2$sex.x <- ifelse(is.na(df2$sex.y), df2$sex.x, df2$sex.y); df2$sex.y <- NULL`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you example you have a situation similar to what I show below based on the example from the `merge` function.

```
> (authors <- data.frame(
      surname = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney", "Ripley", "McNeil")),
      nationality = c("US", "Australia", "US", "UK", "Australia"),
      deceased = c("yes", rep("no", 3), "yes")))

   surname nationality deceased
1    Tukey          US      yes
2 Venables   Australia       no
3  Tierney          US       no
4   Ripley          UK       no
5   McNeil   Australia      yes

> (books <- data.frame(
      name = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney",
                 "Ripley", "Ripley", "McNeil", "R Core")),
      title = c("Exploratory Data Analysis",
                "Modern Applied Statistics ...", "LISP-STAT",
                "Spatial Statistics", "Stochastic Simulation",
                "Interactive Data Analysis",
                "An Introduction to R"),
      deceased = c("yes", rep("no", 6))))

      name                         title deceased
1    Tukey     Exploratory Data Analysis      yes
2 Venables Modern Applied Statistics ...       no
3  Tierney                     LISP-STAT       no
4   Ripley            Spatial Statistics       no
5   Ripley         Stochastic Simulation       no
6   McNeil     Interactive Data Analysis       no
7   R Core          An Introduction to R       no

> (m1 <- merge(authors, books, by.x = "surname", by.y = "name"))

   surname nationality deceased.x                         title deceased.y
1   McNeil   Australia        yes     Interactive Data Analysis         no
2   Ripley          UK         no            Spatial Statistics         no
3   Ripley          UK         no         Stochastic Simulation         no
4  Tierney          US         no                     LISP-STAT         no
5    Tukey          US        yes     Exploratory Data Analysis        yes
6 Venables   Australia         no Modern Applied Statistics ...         no
```

Where `authors` might represent your first dataframe and `books` your second and `deceased` might be the value that is in both dataframe but only up to date in one of them (`authors`).

The easiest way to only include the correct value of `deceased` would be to simply exclude the incorrect one from the merge.

```
> (m2 <- merge(authors, books[names(books) != "deceased"], 
               by.x = "surname", by.y = "name"))

   surname nationality deceased                         title
1   McNeil   Australia      yes     Interactive Data Analysis
2   Ripley          UK       no            Spatial Statistics
3   Ripley          UK       no         Stochastic Simulation
4  Tierney          US       no                     LISP-STAT
5    Tukey          US      yes     Exploratory Data Analysis
6 Venables   Australia       no Modern Applied Statistics ...
```

The line of code `books[names(books) != "deceased"]` simply subsets the dataframe `books` to remove the `deceased` column leaving only the correct `deceased` column from `authors` in the final merge.

Comment: The problem is that  the dataframe Animals has more animals than dataframe Farm, so i cant just remove sex.x

Comment: This is why a reproducible example that demonstrates the challenges you are trying to overcome is important.  In that case, I would recommend the solution in the comments below the question by @rawr